# Uploading Compiled codes on server

Tags: uploading, compiled

i wanted to know whats the advantage and difference between uploading normal content to the server and uploading compiled codes on the server. does it makes any difference in the sites performance if i upload the content in the compiled form...

Please reply with the suggestion and information as soon as possible..
Thanks and Regards
Abbas Electricwala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924195/converting-the-code-into-compiled-code-on-server
you already asked this please do not make duplicate questions and accept some answers or people will be less reluctant to help you